# comparison between various method to get size of a string

Tags: c++, string, time-complexity

which way of finding the size of the string in a loop is efficient.
what is time complexity comparison of these methods?

```
   for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
   {
    //statements
   }

  for(int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
  {
    //statements
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
  {
    //statements
  }
```

how strlen different from size()?

Comment: What do you think the time complexity is? Why?

Comment: Depending on what `s` is, some variants might lead to build errors.

Comment: If you read the description of `size()`, which specifies its mathematical complexity, and then read the description of `strlen()`, which will explain its mathematical complexity, you will be able to answer this question yourself. If you are not familiar with the concept of mathematical complexity, and the big-Oh notation, then perhaps you want to focus on learning this first.

Comment: `for (const auto c : s)` is probably what you *really* want.

Comment: A modern compiler may way optimise `strlen(s)` but I wouldn't rely on that if I were you; particularly if `s` is not `const` and if the loop body reads `s`. In your first way, beware the pitfalls in matching signed and unsigned types. `for (auto&& c: s)` is probably the best way, in the absence of any other information.

Answer (score 2):

All 3 methods are different and will provide different results.

`std::string::size` is the only method that provides real length of `std::string`. Note that `std::string` can store and handle null (`\0`) bytes perfectly fine.

`s[i] != '\0'` will stop at first null byte, which may or may not be the end of the string. In particular, before C++11, `myString[myString.size()]` is **not guaranteed** to return null byte and has UB in non-const environment. It also requires access to char at every iteration (though compiler will probably optimize usage in loop control and later in body).

`strlen()` doesn't work with `std::string` at all (unless you extract pointer to char array with `c_str()`). It also has O(n) time complexity.

---

This being said, difference is likely completely irrelevant. You won't notice any difference at all between any of these versions. Unless you have profiled your code and found out this is a bottleneck (highly unlikely), *don't bother with optimizing*. Focus on maintaining high readability.

High readability can be achieved by using `size()` method, higher with range-based loop (`for (const auto c : s)`, as suggested in comments) and the highest with not using loop at all and utilizing functions from `<algorithm>` library instead.

Comment: According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at `str[str.size()]` returns `\0` pre c++11 too

Comment: @AlanBirtles Where? It's only guaranteed for the `const` version. Otherwise, it's UB.

Comment: Yep, and `s[i] != '\0'` would use the `const` version